# After importing an exported table into a new database, the data occupies a significantly larger amount of disk space

Tags: sql-server

I came across this issue while troubleshooting a problem that I described in [another post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243475/attempts-to-reclaim-unused-space-causes-the-used-space-to-increase-significantly), but I thought this deserves a post of its own.

I'm trying to reclaim some unused space in a table. This is the current disk usage report for the table:

[image: Unused Space]

This is the current disk usage report for the database:
[image: Unused Space]

As an experiment, I did the following:

1. Used the bcp utility to export the table contents:

```
EXECUTE sys.xp_cmdshell 'bcp MyDb.dbo.MyTable out c:\bcp\MyTable.bcp -n -S MyServer -T'
```

2. Created a new database.
3. Created the table with its schema in the new database:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTable](
    [Column1]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column2]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column3]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column4]  [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Column5]  [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Column6]  [datetime] NULL,
    [Column7]  [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column8]  [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Column9]  [varchar](256) NULL,
    [Column10] [int] NULL,
    [Column11] [varbinary](max) NULL,
    [Column12] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [Column13] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Column14] [varchar](6) NULL,
    [Column15] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Column16] [bit] NOT NULL,
    [Column17] [datetime] NULL,
    [Column18] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column19] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column20] [varchar](60) NULL,
    [Column21] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Column22] [varchar](120) NULL,
    [Column23] [varchar](4) NULL,
    [Column24] [varchar](75) NULL,
    [Column25] [char](1) NULL,
    [Column26] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column27] [varchar](128) NULL,
    [Column28] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Column29] [int] NULL,
    [Column30] [varchar](max) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Column1] ASC,
    [Column2] ASC,
    [Column3] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Column4]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Column4]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Column5]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Column5]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Column15]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Column15]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[MyTable] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_Column16]  DEFAULT (0) FOR [Column16]
GO
```

4. Inserted the exported data into the new table:

```
BULK INSERT dbo.MyTable FROM 'c:\bcp\MyTable.bcp' 
WITH (
DATAFILETYPE = 'native', 
ORDER(Column1,Column2,Column3), 
TABLOCK, 
KEEPIDENTITY
)
```

Now here are the disk usage reports for the new database:

[image]
[image]

We can see that we've eliminated most of the unused space, but the space for the data has gone way up, from 4.5 GB to 8.2 GB, resulting in a negligible change in the overall space.

So, why is this happening? Is this kind of outcome expected?

Comment: Are both SQL Server the same version? What is the fragmentation of the page in the first and in the second table?