# DBCC SHRINKFILE has no effect

Tags: sql-server

I came across this issue while troubleshooting a problem that I described in [another post](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243475/attempts-to-reclaim-unused-space-causes-the-used-space-to-increase-significantly), but I thought this deserves a post of its own.

I'm trying to reclaim some unused space in a table. This is the current disk usage report for the table:

[image: Unused Space]

This is the current disk usage report for the database:
[image: Unused Space]

I'm aware that shrinking a database is generally considered bad practice, but I wanted to see what kind of effect it would have in this situation.

I executed this command:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE("MyDbFile", 0)
```

Here is the result of the command:

[image]

Now here are the disk usage reports after the shrink:

[image]

[image]

Why does it seem like the shrink operation had virtually no effect? I have read that this operation can't shrink a database below it's initial size, but the mimimum database size seems to be set to 640 KB.

Comment: What do the messages say in ssms after running the command?

Comment: @Randi Vertongen It says "Query executed successfully" and prints the table that I included in the post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Attempts to reclaim unused space causes the used space to increase significantly in SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/243475/attempts-to-reclaim-unused-space-causes-the-used-space-to-increase-significantly) - voting as such since this feels like a subset of the original post, and a solve for this Q would essentially solve the original Q as well for practical purposes.